# How to automatically update (promote/demote) heading sub-levels

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

How can the heading sub-levels can be automatically updated when promoting/demoting a section? Imagine I have a document structured like this:

```
    (1)Chapter A
        (2)Section B
        (2)Section C
            (3)sub-section D
            (3)sub-section E
                (4)sub-sub-section F
            . . .
```

and I want to promote the 'Section C' to chapter level (heading 1). I'd like all the 'Section C' sub-levels to be updated automatically - doing it manually is not trivial when the document has a lot of sub-sections and content. The question refers also to the reverse case when, for example, I want to demote the 'Section C' back to heading level 2.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Navigator pane (from View menu, or the sidebar).
Select Section C.
Click on the button "Promote Level" («).

All sub-levels are updated automatically. Unfortunately you cannot select many Sections at once.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically (as far as I know) - but you can save lots of work:

- Select the Chapter to change levels for
- Search -> More options -> Search for templates + in selection only
- Replace "Heading 4" -> "Heading 3" and "Heading 5" -> "Heading 4"

(Please note that the wording might be different, I have no English OOo version)